# SQL Like query to get closest match to the parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am implementing search using a sql, this is the query

```
Select CM.ID, ProductName,ImageURL,SKU,AA.Name as
MemberName,Price,Discount,DM.Name as CategoryName from tblMasterProduct CM
INNER JOIN tblProducts OM ON CM.ID=OM.MasterProductID
INNER JOIN tblMasterCategory DM ON CM.SubCategoryID=DM.ID
INNER JOIN tblOnlineRetailMember AA ON OM.MemberID=AA.ID
WHERE 1=1  AND  CM.ProductName LIKE '% watches %'  AND CM.SubCategoryID= 112 
AND (OM.Price - OM.Discount) BETWEEN 0 And 200000
```

The issue is that the the query returns results containing the word watches, whereas i would also like to get all the entries containing the word "Watch" too.

EDIT: Sorry for incomplete information, The query is written in a stored procedure and the string is entered by the user, cannot get "Watch" from the user.

Comment: when you query for `% watches %` (with a space before and after) e.g. `smartwatches`will NOT be returned. When you query for `%watch%` you wil get everything that contains `watch`. watches, smartwatches, watch, watching,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [SOUNDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) or [DIFFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) functions in MSSQL. If `ProductName` is a multi word then you can use [PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) to split to words and use DIFFERENCE to find one similar word in a string:

```
select * from t WHERE DIFFERENCE(ProductName,'watches')>=3
```

<kbd>[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa00c/6)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR ..

```
Select CM.ID, ProductName,ImageURL,SKU,AA.Name as
MemberName,Price,Discount,DM.Name as CategoryName from tblMasterProduct CM
INNER JOIN tblProducts OM ON CM.ID=OM.MasterProductID
INNER JOIN tblMasterCategory DM ON CM.SubCategoryID=DM.ID
INNER JOIN tblOnlineRetailMember AA ON OM.MemberID=AA.ID
WHERE 1=1  AND  ( CM.ProductName LIKE '%watches%' or CM.ProductName LIKE '%watch%'  ) AND CM.SubCategoryID= 112 
AND (OM.Price - OM.Discount) BETWEEN 0 And 200000
```

Comment: Please check the Edited question again.

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve it by **`OR`**.

**Query**

```
Select CM.ID, ProductName,ImageURL,SKU,AA.Name as MemberName,
Price,Discount,DM.Name as CategoryName from tblMasterProduct CM
INNER JOIN tblProducts OM ON CM.ID=OM.MasterProductID
INNER JOIN tblMasterCategory DM ON CM.SubCategoryID=DM.ID
INNER JOIN tblOnlineRetailMember AA ON OM.MemberID=AA.ID
WHERE 1=1  AND  ( CM.ProductName LIKE '%watches%' OR CM.ProductName LIKE '%watch%' ) 
AND CM.SubCategoryID= 112 
AND (OM.Price - OM.Discount) BETWEEN 0 And 200000;
```

Comment: Please check the Edited question again.

Comment: @user2417160 : user entering watches?

Comment: Yes the user is entering watches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for dynamic query, this works

```
Select CM.ID, ProductName,ImageURL,SKU,AA.Name as MemberName,
Price,Discount,DM.Name as CategoryName from tblMasterProduct CM
INNER JOIN tblProducts OM ON CM.ID=OM.MasterProductID
INNER JOIN tblMasterCategory DM ON CM.SubCategoryID=DM.ID
INNER JOIN tblOnlineRetailMember AA ON OM.MemberID=AA.ID
WHERE 1=1  AND  ( CM.ProductName LIKE '%watches %' 
OR CHARINDEX(LEFT('watches',len('watches')-1) ,CM.ProductName) > 0 --watche
OR CHARINDEX(LEFT('watches',len('watches')-2) ,CM.ProductName) > 0 --watch
) 
AND CM.SubCategoryID= 112 
AND (OM.Price - OM.Discount) BETWEEN 0 And 200000;
```

Comment: The query does not return any results.

Comment: i have removed the space at left LIKE '%watches %', please add space and try,  ---------LIKE '% watches %' ------------